# How to implement IViewFor<T> in addition to inheriting from ReactiveUserControl<T>?

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

Is it possible to implement `IViewFor<MainViewModel>` in addition to inheriting from `ReactiveUserControl<Job>`?

My attempt leads to an error

> InvalidCastException 'Unable to cast object of type 'Job' to type 'MainViewModel'

**Background**

I have a POCO-model called `Job`. A `MainViewModel` with a `ObservableCollection<Job>`. A `MainWindow` with an `ItemsControl` that is bound via reactiveui binding.

The `Splat.Locator` automagically displays the `JobView`. This `JobView` needs to bind properties of `MainViewModel`. As `this.Bind(..)` only works if `IViewFor<MainViewModel>` is implemented, I did just that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is possible in a clean way. First, your class would need two different implementations of the strongly-typed ViewModel property for the two different types `Job` and `MainViewModel`.
The answer by `mm8` addresses this issue by defining the custom implementation of `IViewModelFor<MainViewModel>` explicitely.
However, `IViewModelFor<>` also inherits from the non-generic `IViewModelFor` and `IActivatableViewModel`. While the latter is a pure marker interface, the first requires you to implement:

```
object IViewFor.ViewModel { get ;set; }
```

two work with both types which is not possible in a consistent way at least for the getter. This implementation is used within the architecture of ReactiveUI. The implementation in `ReactiveUserControl<T>` looks like this:

```
/// <inheritdoc/>
object? IViewFor.ViewModel
{
    get => ViewModel;
    set => ViewModel = (TViewModel?)value;
}
```

This cast is probably causing your exception.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, if you implement it explicitly:

```
public class MyView : ReactiveUserControl<Job>, IViewFor<MainViewModel>
{
    ...
    MainViewModel IViewFor<MainViewModel>.ViewModel
    {
        get;set;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I tried and lead to the `InvalidCastException` at runtime. How would you then bind to the `MainViewModel`?

Comment: How do you currently bind?